# Getting integers seperatly from a string and giving directions to a robot

Tags: java, exception, project, instructions

I am working on a project which involves making a "worker" in java which receives instructions from an input string. In the input string normally should be first four numbers and then afterwards a number and a letter right after being N,S,W, or E. The first 2 numbers in the list are used to determine the size of the area this worker can walk. the next two numbers are the starting point for the worker. The number with the letter determines what direction the worker walks and how many paces. The problem I am having is I don't understand how to get the first four digits out of the string and separate them into what they each should be.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Worker {
private int height;
public void readInstructions(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) throws InvalidWorkerInstructionException{
    try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFileName);
    PrintWriter wrt;
        wrt = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    if(inputFileName.startsWith("i")){
        System.out.println("Input file not found.");
        //wrt.println("Input file not found.");
    }
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String s = in.nextLine();
        if(Integer.parseInt(s)<= 9){

        }
    }
    }catch(InvalidWorkerInstructionException e){

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

    }
```

While I would love to ask for a straight up answer, this is a project so I would prefer nobody gives me a fixed code. Please if you can give me advice for what I am doing wrong and where I should be going to solve the problem.

Ok I realized one other thing because I tried the advice given. So I am receiving a string that gives me the name of an input txt. Inside that input txt is the numbers and directions. How can i access this text file? Also how do I determine if it can be opened?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you already know how to read the file using a `Scanner`. All you need to do next is split the String and extract the first four inputs out of it.

Here is the code snippet:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
int i = 0, digits[] = new int[4];
for(String inp : s.splits(" ")) {
    if(i == 4) break;
    digits[i++] = Integer.parseInt(inp);
}
```

**Note:** I'm assuming that the inputs in your file is space separated. If not then you can replace the space in the `split()` with the correct delimiter.

Comment: I added to my question due to a snag im having making this not work. Do u know what would fix it?

Comment: @Darkhail I hope you are getting the full path and not just the filename in `inputFileName` and your program is able to open the input file. You are reading the file contents just fine but you can do something like this: `if(Integer.parseInt(s) <= 9) { /*...*/ }` if and only if each and every instruction in your file is separated by a line.

Answer (score 0):

If input format is fixed than you can use substring method to get different parts of string. Refer documentation for more detail:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Example code:

```
    String s = "12345E";
    s.substring(0, 2); /* 12 */
    s.substring(2, 4); /* 34 */
    s.substring(4, 5); /* 5 */
    s.substring(5, 6); /* E */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method .getChars() to accomplish this. Here is what the javadoc says about this method:

public void getChars(int srcBegin,
            int srcEnd,
            char[] dst,
            int dstBegin)
Copies characters from this string into the destination character array.
The first character to be copied is at index srcBegin; the last character to be copied is at index srcEnd-1 (thus the total number of characters to be copied is srcEnd-srcBegin). The characters are copied into the subarray of dst starting at index dstBegin and ending at index:

```
 dstbegin + (srcEnd-srcBegin) - 1
```

Parameters:
srcBegin - index of the first character in the string to copy.
srcEnd - index after the last character in the string to copy.
dst - the destination array.
dstBegin - the start offset in the destination array.
Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - If any of the following is true:
srcBegin is negative.
srcBegin is greater than srcEnd
srcEnd is greater than the length of this string
dstBegin is negative
dstBegin+(srcEnd-srcBegin) is larger than dst.lengt....

Here is what you could do...
You read in the string - grab its length (You want to make sure that it has all the chars you need)
Read in to a separate array discarding any extraneous chars that are not needed for this functionality..
You can make your own pseudo code to work out the problem once the string is split into an array. Very easy to work with since you know what each location of the array is supposed to do.

This is not a hard problem to solve at all..

Good luck on your project.